# Tarjan algorithm, recursion mistakes

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement the Tarjan's algorithm (to find strongly connected components in a graph).

I'm stuck in the dfs part of the algorithm where the components counter does not update itself properly. I think it's a problem with my recursion method but I'm not able able to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
def dfs_scc(graph, node, components_c, nodes_c, connected_components, visited_nodes):
    nodes_c+=1
    connected_components[node]=-nodes_c
    visited_nodes.append(node)
    last=nodes_c
    for adj in graph.get_adj(node):
        if (connected_components[adj[1]]==0):
            b=dfs_scc(graph, adj[1], components_c, nodes_c, connected_components, visited_nodes)
            last=min(last, b)
        elif (connected_components[adj[1]]<0): last=min(last, -connected_components[adj[1]])
    if (last==-connected_components[node]):
        components_c+=1
        print('VISITED NODE QUEUE: ', list(visited_nodes), '; COMPONENTS COUNTER: ', components_c)
        while(visited_nodes[-1]!=node):
            w=visited_nodes.pop()
            connected_components[w]=components_c
        w=visited_nodes.pop()
        connected_components[w]=components_c
    return last
```

And here the output:

```
VISITED NODE QUEUE: [0, 1, 6, 2, 4, 5, 7] ; COMPONENTS COUNTER: 1
VISITED NODE QUEUE: [0, 1, 6, 2, 4, 5] ; COMPONENTS COUNTER: 1
VISITED NODE QUEUE: [0, 1, 6] ; COMPONENTS COUNTER: 1 
VISITED NODE QUEUE: [3] ; COMPONENTS COUNTER: 1
----------------------
CONNECTED COMPONENT: {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}
```

As you can see the queue of the visited nodes remove elements in the right order, at first recursion the node 7 is popped out course is just it's in that components; at next recursion the node 2, 4 and 5 are removed belonging to the same component and so on.

Instead in the final line of the output I've a dictionary (node : component) in which the component value is always the same.

Have any idea?

As asked here is the entire code:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, graph=None):
        if graph == None: graph = {}
        self.__graph = graph

    def get_nodes(self): return list(self.__graph.keys())

    def get_edges(self): return self.__generate_edges()

    def __generate_edges(self):
        edges = []
        for node in self.__graph:
            for adj in self.__graph[node]:
                if node!=adj: edges.append((node, adj))
        return edges

    def add_node(self, node):
        if node not in self.__graph: self.__graph[node] = []

    def add_edge(self, edge):
        if edge[0] in self.__graph: self.__graph[edge[0]].append(edge[1])
        else:self.__graph[edge[0]] = [edge[1]]

    def get_adj(self, node):
        adj=[]
        for edge in self.__generate_edges():
            if node==edge[0] and edge[0]!=edge[1]: adj.append(edge)
        return adj

def scc(graph):
    #connected_components : {npde0: components, node1: components, node2: components, node3 : components, ...}
    connected_components={graph.get_nodes()[i]: 0 for i in range(len(graph.get_nodes()))}
    components_c=nodes_c=0
    visited_nodes=deque()
    for node in graph.get_nodes():
        if (connected_components[node]==0):
            dfs_scc(graph, node, components_c, nodes_c, connected_components, visited_nodes)
    return connected_components


def dfs_scc(graph, node, components_c, nodes_c, connected_components, visited_nodes):
    nodes_c+=1
    connected_components[node]=-nodes_c
    visited_nodes.append(node)
    last=nodes_c
    for adj in graph.get_adj(node):
        if (connected_components[adj[1]]==0):
            b=dfs_scc(graph, adj[1], components_c, nodes_c, connected_components, visited_nodes)
            last=min(last, b)
        elif (connected_components[adj[1]]<0):
            last=min(last, -connected_components[adj[1]])
    if (last==-connected_components[node]):
        components_c+=1
        print('VISITED NODE QUEUE: ', list(visited_nodes), '; COMPONENTS COUNTER: ', components_c)
        while(visited_nodes[-1]!=node):
            w=visited_nodes.pop()
            connected_components[w]=components_c
        w=visited_nodes.pop()
        connected_components[w]=components_c
    return last


def main():
    g={0: [1, 2], 1: [6], 2: [4], 3: [], 4: [5], 5: [2, 7], 6: [0], 7: []}
    graph=Graph(g)
    # nodes=random.randint(1, 10)
    # for i in range(nodes): graph.add_node(i)
    # for i in range(0, nodes):
    #     for j in range(0, nodes):
    #         graph.add_edge((i, j))
    cc=scc(graph)
    print("CONNECTED COMPONENTS: ", cc)
```

Comment: I think you might get answers if you add the code that creates the graph you seem to refer to, and that makes the call to this function. Also, we cannot know what `get_adj` returns, what the initial values are of the arguments passed to this function, ...etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've just edited this post with the all code. I thought the other part of this program does not care about component_c variable (of course something is missing in my mind) as it's called just in dfs_scc function in order to count components during dfs. Maybe something is wrong with conditions and variable declarations during recursion, but I really don't know .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the modification that a function execution brings to `components_c`, `nodes_c`, must carry back to the caller's variables with the same name, but that is not happening, because these variables are local to their own function execution context. The caller's variables with those names will not be modified by the recursive calls it makes, but they should.

You can solve this in different ways. One way is to make `dfs_scc` a function that is defined within `scc`, and to only define the two variables mentioned above in the scope of `scc`. Then `dfs_scc` can reference those variables via the `nonlocal` keyword instead of getting them as arguments, and so modify them in a way that will be seen by all execution contexts in the recursion tree.

Here is how that looks:

```
def scc(graph):
    components_c=nodes_c=0

    # define the recursive function with the scope where the above variables are defined
    def dfs_scc(graph, node, connected_components, visited_nodes):
        nonlocal components_c, nodes_c # reference those variables

        nodes_c+=1
        connected_components[node]=-nodes_c
        visited_nodes.append(node)
        last=nodes_c
        for adj in graph.get_adj(node):
            if (connected_components[adj[1]]==0):
                b=dfs_scc(graph, adj[1], connected_components, visited_nodes)
                last=min(last, b)
            elif (connected_components[adj[1]]<0):
                last=min(last, -connected_components[adj[1]])
        if (last==-connected_components[node]):
            components_c+=1
            print('VISITED NODE QUEUE: ', list(visited_nodes), '; COMPONENTS COUNTER: ', components_c)
            while(visited_nodes[-1]!=node):
                w=visited_nodes.pop()
                connected_components[w]=components_c
            w=visited_nodes.pop()
            connected_components[w]=components_c
        return last
    #connected_components : {npde0: components, node1: components, node2: components, node3 : components, ...}
    connected_components={graph.get_nodes()[i]: 0 for i in range(len(graph.get_nodes()))}
    visited_nodes=deque()
    for node in graph.get_nodes():
        if (connected_components[node]==0):
            dfs_scc(graph, node, connected_components, visited_nodes)
    return connected_components
```

Comment: Wow, that's massive, thanks a lot. So, if I understood, maybe in my version of code I should have reused variables from the scc function to get their modifications after recursion, instead from dfs_scc; couse as I did I lost their changes during recursion. On the other hand with nested function I can use nonlocal keyword to refer to the variable of the outer function. Is that right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *reused*: when you pass primitive values (as integers) as arguments, there is no way to have those modified for the caller. Yes, the `nonlocal` keyword is the way to tell Python that the variable you use inside the function is in fact not a local variable, but a variable in the outer scope.